# Access denied exception when trying to execute an exe on remote machine

Tags: powershell, remote-debugging, psexec

I am trying to execute an exe on machine B from machine A. I have logged on to machine A as userx and trying to run the exe on machine B as usery.

usery is system admin on machine A as well as B.

i tried using PsExec to execute an exe as well as invoke-command to execute a script in both the case am getting access denied exception in spite on passing credential of usery in both case

```
invoke-command -computername "machineB" -scriptBlock { c:\psscript.ps1 } -credential $useryCred

psExec \\machineB c:\exec.exe -u usery -p ypass
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Update:

simple scripts gets executed with out any hassle but this script is trying to create a process on remote machine under the userY's credential !

is it something related to mapping of incoming request to different user say guest ?

regards,
jeez

Comment: Did you enable [psremoting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315349.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

are there 3 machine's involved? it sounds like you are remoting from A to B and the script on B is remoting to C - is that right?

How are you supplying the credentials (for userY)?

I wonder if it's double hop related... if it is and your on windows 2008 you can try using CredSSP.

Here's some links to help explain it better than I would:

http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1230

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/06/05/credssp-for-second-hop-remoting-part-i-domain-account.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2009/06/25/9803001.aspx

and  `Get-Help credssp` displays the commands that you'll need.

HTH,
Matt